# Assignment of array only succeeds when assigning each individual element in a loop

Tags: c, arrays

I've got a bunch of these:

```
static const int blockFrames1[4][9]= {{0,1,1, 0,1,1, 0,1,1},{0,0,0, 1,1,1, 1,1,1},{0,1,1, 0,1,1, 0,1,1},{0,0,0, 1,1,1, 1,1,1}};
```

and I want to assign one of the inner arrays to a temporary variable to use within a function like so:

```
int tempArr[9];
if(type == 1){  
    tempArr[9] = blockFrames1[0];
}else if(type ==2){
    tempArr[9] = blockFrames2[0];
}
(for loop thru and do some stuff with tempArr)
```

But the only way I can get this to work and give me the right numbers is to actually loop through and assign each number:

```
 if(type == 1){
     for (int vv=0; vv<9; vv++) {
         tempArr[vv] = blockFrames1[0][vv];
     }
}
```

Seems like I need the `[9]` when declaring the `tempArr` to define the length,  but then it screws up when I try and assign one of my existing arrays to this new one with or without the `[9]`.

Comment: If your not modifying tempArr why not just set tmpArr = blockFrames{1,2} ?

Comment: C does not permit array assignment.

Comment: I meant int *tempArr[] and than do the assignment of pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Arrays are not assignable.** If you want to fill them, then just `memcpy()`. Also, yes, you need the dimensions in the declaration (well, not if you initialize the array), but if you use the square bracket syntax outside the declaration, then that's already indexing/subscripting the array, so that accesses its elements.

All in all:

```
// declaration
int array[9];

// assignment to one element
array[0] = 42;

// "assignment" to another array - rather a bytewise copy
int other_array[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
memcpy(array, other_array, sizeof(array));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Worked like a charm